# How to count variable ranges of numbers in a vector with count_if

Tags: c++

I need to count how often ranges of numbers appears in a vector

For example, I want to know how many times 2, 3, 4 appear in the vector vec below.

```
std::vector<int> vec = {0,3,1,3,2,4,0,1,3,4,2,3,4};
```

result sum[i] = 8

If it's always the same range, no problem:

```
sum[i] = std::count_if(vec.begin(), vec.begin(), [k](int i) { return i >=2 && i <=4; }); //lambda function works
```

BUT I need the sum[i] for different ranges in a for loop e.g. 2,3,4, later 0,1,2 and that doesn't work.

```
int a = 0;
int b = 0;

// some computation
a = 2;
b = a+2;

sum[i] = std::count_if(vec.begin(), vec.begin(), [k](int i) { return i >=a && i <=b; }); //doesn't work as a and b are not constant.
```

Is there a way to apply dynamic ranges to count_if in a for loop?

Comment: What is `k` and why is it there?

Comment: `std::count_if` is for simple counting. If your task involves more than just simple counting, then use `std::for_each`, and do whatever you want. `std::count_if` is just a `std::for_each`, with a closure that must return a `bool`, and the number of times the closure returns `true` gets added up. Lose the middleman, and use `std::for_each` yourself.

Comment: Capture `a` and `b` the same way you've captured `k`?

Answer (score 1):

The first part of a lambda (where you have `k`) defines what is "captured" by that lambda, effectively bringing them into the lambda's scope. So you can define your lambda like so:

```
[a,b](int i) { return i >= a && i < b; }
```

Just a bit more info: doing it like so will *copy* `a` and `b` into the lambda.  If you want the lambda to *reference* the variable, you can add a `&` like `[&a,&b]`. These can be mixed. If you don't want to list everything explicitly, you can have the compiler auto-detect what is used and `[=]` copy them into the lambda, or `[&]` reference them in the lambda.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation on lambda - problem solved

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues in your code:

```
sum[i] = std::count_if(vec.begin(), vec.begin(), [k](int i) { return i >=a && i <=b; });
```

The `first` and the `last` iterators in `count_if` are both `vec.begin()`. The `last` iterator should be `vec.end()`.

The capture expression `[]` of the lambda function has `k`. But `k` is not being used at all in it. In this case, it does not cause any problems. But only capture what will be used in it.

If you want to use the values of `a`, `b` in your lambda, you need to capture them in the capture expression.
Then your code becomes:

```
std::count_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [a, b](int i) { return (i >= a && i <=b) ; });
```